# Set Stash variable in Channel entry loop, then use in email contact form? Parse order issues?

Tags: templates, stash, parse-order

The following is part of an embedded template, which is passed `{embed:advertisers_entry_id}` that contains a string like `34|68|124|`:

```
{!-- Set defaults --}
{exp:stash:recipients}{/exp:stash:recipients}
{exp:stash:user_recipients}no{/exp:stash:user_recipients}

{!-- Set Stash variables for email contact form --}
{exp:stash:set parse_conditionals="yes" parse_tags="yes"}
    {exp:channel:entries
        channel="advertisers"
        disable="categories|category_fields|pagination"
        entry_id="{embed:advertisers_entry_id}"
    }
        {if {absolute_results} == 1}
            {stash:recipients}{if "{advertiser_email}"}{advertiser_email}{if:else}{author}{/if}{/stash:recipients}
        {if:else}
            {stash:user_recipients}yes{/stash:user_recipients}
        {/if}
    {/exp:channel:entries}
{/exp:stash:set}

{!-- Use Stash variables in email contact form --}
{exp:email:contact_form
    charset="utf-8"
    form_class="customer-email-form"
    recipients="{exp:stash:recipients}"
    user_recipients="{stash:user_recipients}"
}
{/exp:email:contact_form}
```

The goal is to setup the email contact form to send to either one recipient or multiple sender-specified recipients. Unfortunately, the above code is not working properly and I suspect it's a parse order issue.

It seems like the Channel entry loop is not occuring, and thus my Stash variables are not getting set properly for the email contact form.

**Questions:**

1. How do I make the Channel entry loop work?
2. Once the Stash variables are properly set within the Channel entry loop, how do I use it in the email contact form?

I've tried various combinations of `parse="inward"`, `process="end"`, `parse_vars="yes"`, etc. No go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmm,

Using `{stash:set}` in your example will only ever record your last record. You could be better off using `{exp:stash:append}`

```
{exp:channel:entries
   channel="advertisers"
   disable="categories|category_fields|pagination"
   entry_id="{embed:advertisers_entry_id}"}
    //This will give a comma separated string
    {exp:stash:append parse_conditionals="yes" parse_tags="yes"}
      {stash:recipients}
        {if {absolute_results} == 1}
          {if advertiser_email}{advertiser_email},{if:else}{author},{/if}
        {/if}
      {/stash:recipients}
    {/exp:stash:append}
     //This is just set on the last entry
     {exp:stash:set name="user_recipients"}
       {if '{absolute_results}' != '1'}yes{/if}
     {/exp:stash:set}
{/exp:channel:entries}

{!-- Use Stash variables in email contact form --}
{exp:stash:parse} //Wrapping this ensures all stash'ing takes place before we use the values.
{exp:email:contact_form
    charset="utf-8"
    form_class="customer-email-form"
    recipients="{exp:stash:recipients}"
    user_recipients="{stash:user_recipients}"
}
{/exp:email:contact_form}
{/exp:stash:parse}
```

Ignoring the form part for now, output the results:

```
recipients = {exp:stash:recipients}
users = {stash:user_recipients}
```

This is all top-of-the-head, so dont take it as verbatim solution :)

Comment: I understand that it will only ever record my last entry. However, with the conditionals I have, it's fine. If there are only one results, it records the email of that one entry. Otherwise, it sets  `user_recipients` multiple times to "yes" (I don't want "yesyesyesyes"). If there was a way to exist the loop, I would do to when I first set `user_recipients`,

Comment: I don't see anything particularly different with your code besides changing "set" to "append". So, without even trying, I'm guessing this will have the same problem as I already have. Also, being able to use the Stash as a param in the email contact form is also important for me to know how to do; I'm assuming parse order issues there.

Comment: Do you get any results from you stash set at all ? If you do, try wrapping the form in `{exp:stash:parse}` tags

Comment: Can you please update your answer to show how `{exp:stash:parse}` comes into play?

Comment: Comment added. Using parse as per the docs: https://github.com/croxton/Stash/wiki/%7Bexp%3Astash%3Aparse%7D